# Working out integral of $\sin(nx)$ multiplied by its complex conjugate

Tags: integration

I'm trying to find out the reasoning behind the fact that the integral from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ of $\sin(nx)$ multiplied by the complex conjugate of $\sin(nx)$ equals $1/\pi$.

I could make use of the exponential representation of $\sin$, but I get put off by the fact that the complex conjugate of $e^{ix}$ is $e^{-iy}$ where $y$ is the complex conjugate of $x$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we have 
\begin{align*}
  \int_0^{\pi/n} \sin^2(nx)\, dx &= \frac 1n\int_0^\pi \sin^2(y)\, dy\\
       &= \frac{\pi}{2n}.
\end{align*}
As 
$$ \sin(nx) \cdot \overline{\sin(nx)} = \sin^2(nx) , \qquad x \in [-\pi, \pi] $$
and $\sin^2$ is $\pi$-periodic, we get
\begin{align*}
  \int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin^2(nx)\, dx &= 2n\int_0^{\pi/n} \sin^2(nx)\, dx\\
      &= \pi.
\end{align*}

Comment: Excellent - thanks a lot. 

Is $ \sin(nx) \cdot \overline{\sin(nx)} = \sin^2(nx) $ only the case when $ x \in [-\pi, \pi] $ ?